# Expl3 syntax generate error and warning messages for class and LaTeX

Tags: expl3, package-writing, documentclass-writing, error-writing

When I do `\msg_new:nnnn { module } { errorname } { explenation }` and then `\msg_warning { module } { errorname }` i get `Package module Warning:`. How can I get it to say `Class module Warning:` or `LaTeX Warning:` instead? I tried using `LaTeX` instead of `module` which seems to have worked for the error, but nbot for the warning. I also tried `class` instead of `module`, but that did not really work.

Here is a MWE:

```
% Get rid of warnings for filecontents:
\RequirePackage{silence}
\WarningFilter[filecontents]{latex}{Writing or overwriting}
\WarningFilter[filecontents]{latex}{You have requested document class}
\ActivateWarningFilters[filecontents]

% Create class:
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{myclass.cls}
    \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
    \ProvidesClass{Code/CV}[2022/06/06 Curriculum Vitae]
    \LoadClass[a4paper]{article}
    
    % Class warning/error:
    \ExplSyntaxOn
    \msg_new:nnn { Class } { class warning } { this~is~some~class~warning }
    \msg_new:nnn { Class } { class error } { this~is~some~class~error }
    
    \msg_error:nn { Class } { class error }
    \msg_warning:nn { Class } { class warning }
    \ExplSyntaxOff
    
    \endinput
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{myclass}

% Create Package:
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mypack.sty}
    % Package warning/error:
    \ExplSyntaxOn
    \msg_new:nnn { mypack } { mypack error } { this~is~some~package~error.}
    \msg_new:nnn { mypack } { mypack warning } { this~is~some~package~warning.}
    
    \msg_warning:nn { mypack } { mypack warning }
    \msg_error:nn { mypack } { mypack error }
    \ExplSyntaxOff
    
    \endinput
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{mypack}


\begin{document}

% LaTeX3 warning/error:
\ExplSyntaxOn
    \msg_new:nnn { LaTeX } { LaTeX error } { this~is~some~LaTeX~error}
    \msg_new:nnn { LaTeX } { LaTeX warning } { this~is~some~LaTeX~error}
    
    \msg_error:nn { LaTeX } { LaTeX error }
    \msg_warning:nn { LaTeX } { LaTeX warning}
\ExplSyntaxOff

This is a PDF

\end{document}
```

[image]

For some reason, the LaTeX3 warning does not show up and the class error and warnings are not right. What is the problem here? I want it to say `Class myclass error:` like the command `\ClassError{myclass}{ }{ }` does. What is it I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: not related but you shouldn't silence filecontents like that. I would get quite angryif a class would do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `l3msg` module contains a global property list for this mapping. Simply add your class to that property list:

```
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_msg_module_type_prop { mythingy } { Class }
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked for the errors, but now only the package warning shows up. The document warning and LaTeX3 warning does not show up.

Comment: @Vebjorn I can't reproduce that, for me, simply putting an additional line in your `myclass.cls` with `\prop_gput:Nnn \g_msg_module_type_prop { Class } { Class }` works and all the errors and warnings show up.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with me using Overleaf? It seems the warnings show up in the raw log, but not where the other warnings and errors show up...

Comment: @Vebjorn then report that to Overleaf (if their message filter doesn't work correctly that is very concerning!)

Comment: Yes, Overleaf's log parser is partially broken. [I've reported this](https://github.com/overleaf/overleaf/issues/1023) and sent in a fix, but the fix hasn't been activated yet.